# Use Negative numbers in mysql php if statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code with an if statement and the value is negative one is some rows of data. Yet when I use this statement it reads the -1 value as 1.

```
if ($row ['bedrooms'] == '-1')
{
    echo "<td class='propdescres'>Studio</td></tr>";
}
else
{
    echo "<td class='propdescres'>" . $row['bedrooms'] . "</td></tr>";
}
```

I tried adding

```
$studio = $row ['bedrooms']*'-99';
```

And changing my statement to:

```
if ($studio == '99')
{
    echo "<td class='propdescres'>Studio</td></tr>";
}
else
{
    echo "<td class='propdescres'>" . $row['bedrooms'] . "</td></tr>";
```

The following is the query I am using to get the data:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT realty.id, realty.unit_num, realty.address, realty.price, realty.bedrooms, realty.bathrooms, realty.metadesc FROM realty
```

The field type is tinyint(3) and when I query the database for bedrooms = -1 it returns vales but in my echo results in php all the -1 values are 1.

Can somebody please give me a little insight as to what I am doing wrong or how I can retrieve negative values?

Thank you.

Comment: `var_dump($row ['bedrooms']);` returns ?

Comment: By the way, you will be increasing the negative number deeper, rather going to positive. Eg; 9*-9 = -81,

Comment: @DarylGill But OP is expecting `-1`. And `-1*-99 = 99` last time I checked

Comment: but i want to know how he gets negative bedrooms, 0 yes, but negative?

Comment: Then The way forward that I see, would be to check that both numbers have the negative symbol present, use strreplace or a regex (which ever your comfortable with), cast to integer then multiply, if working with negative numbers is a must, I assume your default variable cast would be string, as afaik this is the best approach

Comment: @Dagon Where do I check the var_dump? I have never done this.

Comment: The module was set up to use -1 as the value for a studio apartment, I am now using this data to display on another page. How would I incorporate this code such as strreplace

Comment: @CDdubYaa var_dump($row['bedrooms']);  http://uk1.php.net/var_dump

Comment: Variable Dump = NULL

Comment: need to see more code, such as where you populate `$row`, assume its a db query

Comment: @Dagon I am using while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) the field is tinyint(3), it seems to be giving me a positive value but when I do a query in the mysql database for bedrooms equals -1 it gives me results.

Comment: we don't have the data or your code you have to debug it to find whey the $row ['bedrooms'] is null

Comment: I am running it in this file.

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT realty.id, realty.unit_num, realty.address, realty.price, realty.bedrooms, realty.bathrooms, realty.metadesc
FROM realty

Comment: The rows are being displayed, it is just displaying the value as 1 and not as -1 as it is in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use so:

```
$someNegVal = '-1';
if (isset($row['bedrooms']) &&  $row['bedrooms'] == -1*abs($someNegVal)) {
//....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
if((int)$row['bedrooms'] == -1){
    echo "<td class='propdescres'>Studio</td></tr>";
} else {
    echo "<td class='propdescres'>" . $row['bedrooms'] . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Although (int) will cast the variable to an integer no matter what, you should first confirm that the variable actually returns an integer in the first place.

Comment: @CDubYaa Ofcourse it doesn't work if $row['bedrooms'] is null in the first place. You can't magicly create a value out of a none existent array. If you want us to be able to help you, post all relevant code. Don't expect us to fix what we don't know!

Comment: I have posted additional info above and this is the result of the var_dump: string(1) "2" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "2" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1"

Comment: Thank you, your comment caused me to look deeper and it was a problem with my result set.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you got it sorted out :)